# SimpleSearch как настроить результаты поиска для "no results"? (MODx)

Tags: modx, поиск, revo

Всем привет. Есть сайт на MODx Revolution, в качестве поиска используется SimpleSearch. Подскажите, как настроить внешний вид результатов поиска, если ничего не найдено (no results)?

SimpleSearch использует для этого свой чанк searchnoresults.chunk.tpl. Могу ли я его изменять (или он перепишется потом при обновлении?), или лучше создать новый и в него внести все изменения. Если создавать новый, то где его указывать?

Для обычных результатов (когда товары найдены) создавался отдельный чанк, и я его успешно настроил, потому что его можно было указать в параметрах SimpleSearch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения требуется:

1. Создать [чанк](https://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/structuring-your-site/chunks) с желаемым содержанием. (по умолчанию в чанке **searchnoresults.chunk.tpl** находится: [[%sisea.no_results? &query=`[[+query]]`]], который выводит сообщение, о том, что результатов не найдено из **/lexicon/[язык]/default.inc.php**)
2. При вызове **SimpleSearch**, указать значением параметра **&noResultsTpl** -  имя созданного ранее чанка:

   [[!SimpleSearch? /* ..... */
       &noResultsTpl=`[созданный-чанк]`
       ]]

**ps.** апострофы, к сожалению пропадают, как я понял, в представлении кода (а они так важны для modx). Надеюсь, что понятно - каждое значение при вызове [сниппета](https://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/developing-in-modx/basic-development/snippets) - в апострофах. **``**

Comment: Благодарю! Столько времени прошло)) Проверил, всё работает, с вашей помощью удалось настроить страницу с no results. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Чанк можно указать свой собственный через параметр `&noResultsTpl`.

Comment: Спасибо! Я это проверю и отмечу ваш ответ. Заболел, сейчас посмотреть не могу.

Comment: Старайтесь писать более детальные ответы. Можно включить пример кода, объяснить путь решения, указать на конкретные ошибки, привести ссылки с более подробным разбором проблемы и т. п.